# Before taking eggs from the hens, does the farmer have to chase the hens away?

Tags: halacha, ki-teitzei, shiluach-haken

[Devarim 22:6-7](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.22.6-7?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) mentions that if you find a mother bird sitting on eggs or chicks, you must chase away the mother before you can take the eggs or chicks.

Does this imply that the farmer who collects chicken eggs (for resale, e.g.) must he chase away all the chickens before he collects the eggs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not apply to "planned birds". (Chullin 12:1)

Basically, it has to be that you encounter it in the wild.

Comment: Yes there are people who purposefully declare buildings ownerless and put birds in there to try and set up an artificial "wild". Go figure.